# maven-surefire-plugin ignores argLine when setting forkCount=0

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to update build of my project to not forking process, due to limitation of provided build agents. We run two profiles on each build, with different databases used for testing, each profile set system property like so:

```pom
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=${spring.profiles.active}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ignite</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>ignite</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>oracle</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>oracle</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then different Spring configurations are used depending on `@Profile`.
Now I want to run tests without forking VM, so I configure plugin accordingly:

```pom
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
        <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=${spring.profiles.active}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, surefire-plugin does not use `argLine` on tests run, resulting in empty `spring.profiles.active` system property failure of tests on incomplete configured project. How  do I work this around?

Answer (score 0):

After digging a while on docs page, I found [this setting](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#systempropertyvariables):

> `<systemPropertyVariables>`
> List of System properties to pass to a provider.

That worked, however special properties like `-Xmx` [must be set up externally:](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html#special-vm-properties)

> Some system properties must be set on the command line of the forked VM, and cannot be set after the VM has been started. These properties must be added to the `argLine` parameter of the Surefire plugin.

So my plugin configuration now looks like:

```pom
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <spring.profiles.active>${spring.profiles.active}</spring.profiles.active>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```